# Unable to stop Kerberos debug logging

Tags: java, apache-spark, kerberos

I'm using a Kerberos enabled Spark cluster for running our Spark applications. The Kerberos has been setup previously by other members of the organization, and I have no idea how it works. In the initial days, we had used the Kerberos debug logs to understand the exception "Unable to obtain password from user" which was being raised due to absence of a JCE certificate in the cacerts folder of jre security. However, we no longer require the logs and thus, used the -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=false parameter to disable the logging. However, this did not have any effect. Is there any other parameter that could do the trick? Please help me.

Comment: Nodes sometimes have multiple JVMs installed.  Are you sure you are turning off logging on the correct one?

Comment: Which kind of "debug logs" do you get -- low-level traces from Java core libs, dumped to StdOut and/or StdErr? or Hadoop / Spark log entries tagged `DEBUG` or `TRACE` that Log4J routes to a log file?

Comment: @T-Heron, your comment is interesting. Could you please elaborate on that? I'm starting the Spark submit job on my driver, and all the parameters I'm providing in the command only. How do I ensure that the instruction gets replicated on the workers as well?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, I'm getting the Kerberos debug logs which contain all sorts of octet codes, they are coming in the stdout logs of the worker nodes.

Comment: @T-Heron, there is just one Java installation per node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from the GitBook ***"Hadoop and Kerberos: The Madness Beyond the Gate"*** by Steve Loughran, chapter *[Low-Level Secrets](https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html)*

> #### JVM Library logging
>
> You can turn Kerberos low-level logging on 
> `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true`
>
> This doesn't come out via Log4J, or java.util logging; it just comes
>   out on the console. Which is somewhat inconvenient —but bear in mind
>   they are logging at a very low level part of the system. And it does
>   at least log. If you find yourself down at this level you are in
>   trouble. Bear that in mind.
>
> If you want to debug what is happening in SPNEGO, another system
>   property lets you enable this:
>  `-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true`
>
> You can ask for both of these in the `HADOOP_OPTS` environment variable 
>   `export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true"`
>
> #### Hadoop-side JAAS debugging
>
> Set the env variable `HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG` to true and UGI will set the
>   "debug" flag on any JAAS files it creates.
>
> You can do this on the client, before issuing a hadoop, hdfs or yarn
>   command, and set it in the environment script of a YARN service to
>   turn it on there. 
>   `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true`
>
> On the next Hadoop command, you'll see a trace like *(.........)*

Caveat: the Java properties starting with `sun.security.` apply to Sun/Oracle Java run-time, and also OpenJDK run-time and its variants. But not to IBM Java, etc.

---

Excerpt from the **Java 8 documentation** under *[Troubleshooting Security](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html)*

> If you want to monitor security access, you can set the
>   `java.security.debug` System property. 
>   *(.......)* Separate multiple options with a comma.

When troubleshooting Kerberos specifically, I personally use that combination:
`-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

---

Excerpt from the Oracle **[JDK 9 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-new-features-3745613.html)** section *tools/launcher*

> JDK 9 supports a new environment variable `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` to
>   prepend options to those specified on the command line. The new
>   environment variable has several advantages over the
>   legacy/unsupported `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable including the
>   ability to include java launcher options *(...)*

These two env variables are a very dirty (and utterly difficult to detect) way to inject Java system properties without them appearing on the command line.

---

What does that mean for you? Well, you have to search for multiple Java system props and environment variables, which might be set

- for env variables: globally (cf. `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`), or at account level (cf. `~/.bashrc` and friends), or inside Hadoop "include files", or directly inside a shell script that runs your Spark job
- for system props: in any shell-or-env variable that is later developed in a shell script (...) or any env var picked up by Java on startup, or in YARN configuration files *(when using Spark-on-YARN)*, or directly on a Java command-line

Good luck.
I personally would run a dummy Spark job that just dumps all env variables and Java system props; then inspect the dump to detect what to search for; then run a brute-force `find ... -exec grep ...` on the Linux filesystem *(repeat as needed)*.